# SELECT rows with unique values in two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
id          col1 col2        
----------- ---- ----------- 
1           A    5
2           A    6
3           B    5
4           B    6
5           B    7
6           C    6
7           D    7
```

I need to select no more than one row with any exact value of `col1` or `col2`.
For example one possible solution is:

```
id          col1 col2        
----------- ---- ----------- 
1           A    5
4           B    6
7           D    7
```

Other possible solution is:

```
id          col1 col2        
----------- ---- ----------- 
3           B    5
6           C    6
7           D    7
```

I need to find one of any possible solutions.

The algorithm is very simple:

1. Get any row from table to an output.
2. Exclude all rows from the table
   that have value in `col1` equal to value of `col1` or value in
   `col2` equal to value of `col2` in the selected row.
3. If table is not empty go to step 1.

How to implement this logic in SQL `SELECT` statement?

Code to generate test table:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (id INT IDENTITY, col1 CHAR(1), col2 INT) ;

INSERT  INTO #t (col1, col2)
VALUES  
    ('A', 5),
    ('A', 6),
    ('B', 5),
    ('B', 6),
    ('B', 7),
    ('C', 6),
    ('D', 7);
```

Comment: Surely there are other valid combinations. A5, B7, C6. Seems like something has gone wrong in the table design given the desired output here.

Comment: There are other valid combination A6,B5,D7. .Its not matter. I need to find at least one solution.

Comment: I go back to the design is the problem here. You essentially have a many to many relationship across two columns in a table. When pulling data from a single table becomes this difficult it is a clear indicator that the architecture is not well suited to the needs.

Comment: @SeanLange this simplified task is one of many parts for checkiing and cleaning raw data and converting them to valid relationship design.

Comment: This is a variation of the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). You have to find a row, then compare that row to every other row in the result to determine how to get the most representation. It is even possible to end up with ties. What would be the result if instead of C-6 and D-7 you had C-8 and D-8? Both C and D show up only once and 8 is with both of them. Do you return one of them? If so which one and why?

Comment: In case of C-8, D-8 I need in output only one C-8 or D-8 but not both. In real life `C` and `D` is distinct entities of one kind but some of their properties exactly match to properties of entity `8` of other kind. If we once select entity `8` to an output (C-8 or D-8) then this entity should not more used even it matched to other entities. If after processing of all data there are missing entities of any kind (ex. if we select `C` then `D` will be missing) such entities should be classified as invalid.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  id, col1, col2
FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col2 ) Row#
          FROM      #t
        ) x
WHERE   x.Row# = 1
```

Comment: Its not work. Try your select on table: `INSERT  INTO #t (col1, col2)
VALUES  
    ('A', 5),
    ('A', 6),
    ('B', 5),
    ('B', 6),
    ('B', 7),
    ('C', 6),
    ('D', 8);`  It return table `id          col1 col2        
----------- ---- ----------- 
1           A    5
4           B    6
5           B    7
7           D    8`  Its wrong

Answer (score 0):

try the following using cursor:

```
create table #final (id int, col1 varchar(10), col2 int)

declare @id int, @col1 varchar(10), @col2 int
declare cur cursor for select id, col1, col2 from #t order by newid()

open cur
fetch next from cur into @id, @col1, @col2
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    if (@col1 in (select col1 from #final) or @col2 in (select col2 from #final))
    begin
        fetch next from cur into @id, @col1, @col2
        continue
    end
    insert into #final
    select id, @col1, @col2 from #t where col1 = @col1 and col2 = @col2 and id = @id
    fetch next from cur into @id, @col1, @col2
end

close cur
deallocate cur

select * from #final order by id

drop table #final
```

Result:

[image: Run_result]

Comment: I'm looking for `Select` solution... BTW your code is not correct because col1,col2 pair is not PK. You also need to `fetch` `id` and insert to `#final` only fetched values.

Comment: I have updated the answer with result screenshot and the output of #final seems fine to me.

Comment: Now your answer generate valid output. But cursor style not allow to accept it as valid answer. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy one to solve through straight SQL. I figured I'd give it a crack using a recursive CTE. This spits out all possible combinations, but... in one field called "path" here. Perhaps it will present a way forward using straight tsql.

```
With recCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
      col1, 
      col2, 
      0 as depth, 
      CAST(col1 + '|' + CAST(col2 AS varchar(10)) AS VARCHAR(30)) as path 
    FROM t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT       
      t1.col1, 
      t1.col2, 
      rec.depth + 1, 
      CAST(rec.path + '>' + t1.col1 + '|' + cast(t1.col2 as varchar(10)) as varchar(30))
    FROM t t1
        INNER JOIN recCTE rec
        ON rec.path NOT LIKE '%|' + CAST(t1.col2 as varchar(10)) + '%'
           AND rec.path NOT LIKE '%' + CAST(t1.col2 as varchar(10)) + '|%'
    WHERE depth + 1 <= 3 

)
SELECT * 
FROM recCTE 
WHERE depth = 2
```

Comment: how i can select VALID path from output? BTW #t may contain any count of distinct values in col1 and col2 therefore constants in `depth` condition are not applicable.

Comment: They should all be valid. That's the fun part. Constants are applicable since you say you wanted three distinct. That's your requirement that you specified. Change it to whatever you like

Comment: You can remove depth check in where, or change it to something large and the query will still run. If you have a lot of data though, it could run for a very very long time making an insane number of paths that fit the definition. You can give that top SELECT. Starting position and limit depth though to keep it under control.

Comment: where i say about three distinct? I need all pairs with distinct values.

Comment: I was run your query on test suite and it returns a lot of invalid paths. For an example the latest row contains the path `A|5>A|6>D|7`.
This is invalid because value 'A' encountered more then once.

Comment: May be you did a typo in second `LIKE` and you mean `t1.col1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try  this query:

```
SELECT  id, col1, col2
FROM ( SELECT    * ,
       RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col2 ) Row#
       FROM      #t
     ) x
WHERE   x.Row# = 1
```