# SQL - distinct records across all columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a query that will return a results set that is unique across all records in all rows.

I have a query that returns results such as (where a and b are different table names, and each have a column named "ex"):

```
| a.ex | b.ex |
|a     |1     |
|a     |2     |
|a     |3     |
|b     |2     |
|c     |1     |
|c     |2     |
```

What I want to retrieve is a resultset where only DISTINCT results across both columns are returned, e.g.

```
| a.ex | b.ex |
|a     |3     |
|b     |2     |
|c     |1     |
```

In these results, a.ex has no duplication in the row, b.ex has no duplication in the row.

Stuck on how to approach this!  Ideally, it needs to be SQL and/or PLSQL, but I would normally get the resultset in Java and iterate through, which I can't do in this circumstance.

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the expected result if you add the row (d, 1)?

Comment: What are the rules?  Why a,1 rather than a,3 or c,1 and not c,2 ?

Comment: Interesting that this same question was posed yesterday, but for sql server/tsql. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612642/select-rows-with-unique-values-in-two-columns. Perhaps some of the solutions will translate well to oracle?

Comment: The last post you mentioned @JNevill is exactly what I am trying to achieve with Oracle SQL.  I will have a look and see if it can translate into a solution in Oracle SQL and update my post if I find out how.

Unfortunately, limiting a result from b.ex to min could mean that it appears more than once (e.g. in the example above, we would get a | 1 and c | 1 - I need all values returned in b.ex to be distinct

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values from a.ex associated with unique values from b.ex, then *most of the solutions are dependent on the content of the query you've not shown us!*

If I assume your query looks something like:

```
SELECT a.ex, b.ex
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.id=b.id
```

Then....

```
SELECT c.ex, d.ex
FROM table1 c,
table2 d
WHERE c.id=d.id
AND d.ex IN (
  SELECT b_ex as unique_bex
  FROM (
      SELECT a.ex as a_ex, b.ex AS b_ex
      FROM table1 a, table2 b
      WHERE a.id=b.id
  ) ilv
  GROUP BY a_ex
  HAVING COUNT(*)=1
)
```

(note that your query appears twice in the above, and this query could itself be simplified - I've skipped that for clarity here).

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to do what you need is using **union** and the operator **minus**

UNION combine the result of 2 querys
MINUS is like union but returns only unique rows returned by the first query but not by the second:

you only need to combine both at the same time

```
( select a.ex,b.ex from table1
  minus
  select a.ex,b.ex from table2
)
UNION
( select a.ex,b.ex from table2
  minus
  select a.ex,b.ex from table1
)
```

the first subquery get the unique rows from table1 and the second subquery gets the unique rows from table2, then you only make the union