# SQL Nested Replace Order

Tags: sql, t-sql, replace, nested

Dumb question, but can't seem to find a quick answer... I am creating UDF to replace name prefix with a nested replace... something like this:

```
REPLACE(
 REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
     REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
        @Name
       , 'Mr ', '')
      , 'Mrs ', '')
     , 'Ms ', '')
    , 'Dr ', '')
   , 'Mr. ', '')
  , 'Mrs. ', '')
 , 'Ms. ', '')
, 'Dr. ', '')
```

but want to replace those containing a '.' BEFORE those without. What's the order/hierarchy of nested replace? TIA, Danny

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of the esoteric [parsename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612642/select-rows-with-unique-values-in-two-columns) function like... `PARSENAME(@name, 1)` which will lop off everything before the `.` character. [Example here](http://rextester.com/TOXS13768). This will be a LOT less expensive than a million nested replaces or a UDF for that matter.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion... I know mine is not most efficient method, but was pressed for time. :-)

Comment: For later readers... you can introduce new problems by hacking off everything before the period when working with names as some people use a first initial instead of a full first name.  If you know you will have a prefix in front of every name, then you're fine.  Data sets I work with with will never let me be so lucky. Think F. Murry Abraham, or F. Scott Fitzgerald, or S. Epatha Merkerson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner most Replace will always run first on the character string. So from inner to outer is the order in which they will be executed. I suggest though trying a more elegant approach perhaps through the use of regex and case statements so it might be easier to maintain rather than just having a ton of nested replaces which don't necessarily all do work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a function like this in SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ReplaceNamePrefix]
(@value NVARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @RETURN NVARCHAR(50);
         SET @RETURN = @value;
         SET @RETURN = REPLACE(@RETURN, 'Mrs.', ''); 
         SET @RETURN = REPLACE(@RETURN, 'Mrs', '');
         SET @RETURN = REPLACE(@RETURN, 'Mr.', '');
         SET @RETURN = REPLACE(@RETURN, 'Mr', '');
         SET @RETURN = REPLACE(@RETURN, 'Ms.', '');
         SET @RETURN = REPLACE(@RETURN, 'Ms', ''); 
         SET @RETURN = REPLACE(@RETURN, 'Dr. ', '');
         SET @RETURN = REPLACE(@RETURN, 'Dr', ''); ');
         SET @RETURN = RTRIM(LTRIM(@RETURN));
         RETURN @RETURN;
     END;
```

Use the following command to get your goal:

```
SELECT [dbo].[ReplaceNamePrefix]('Dr. Danny Dennison');
```

the result is: Danny Dennison

[image]

But if you insist on using your own code, use the following:

```
SELECT REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( 'MR  Danny Dennison', 'Mrs.', '' ), 'Mrs', '' ), 'Mr.', '' ), 'Mr', '' ), 'Ms.', '' ), 'Ms', '' ), 'Dr. ', '' ), 'Dr', '' );
```

Comment: If you replace `Mr`, you will not find `Mr.`, `Mrs` or `Mrs.` in the string later on...

Comment: I did create a function. Again, this was something I needed to do quickly with 'easy' code I'm familiar with, but may revise using @BehrouzMoslem's "SET" methodology... assume performance would improve as well. Thanks all!