# T-SQL Get One From List that Includes Pairs of Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two datasets:

id_description

```
id  description
1   The cat sat
2   The dog barked
2   The dog barked
3   The parrot
4   The dog barked
4   The dog barked
```

person_description

```
person  description
John    The cat sat
Jane    The dog barked
James   The parrot
Mary    The dog barked
```

I need to construct a third dataset that looks like this (either of the two options below):

```
id  person  description
1   John    The cat sat
2   Jane    The dog barked
3   James   The parrot
4   Mary    The dog barked

id  person  description
1   John    The cat sat
2   Mary    The dog barked
3   James   The parrot
4   Jane    The dog barked
```

I start by trying this:

```
SELECT distinct a.id, b.person, a.description
FROM id_description a
LEFT OUTER JOIN person_description b ON a.description = b.description
```

This results in this dataset:

```
id  person  description
1   John    The cat sat
2   Jane    The dog barked
2   Mary    The dog barked
3   James   The parrot
4   Jane    The dog barked
4   Mary    The dog barked
```

Because of the join on `description`, `person` can be duplicated for two **or more** `id` numbers. How would I get to my target dataset?

Each `person` and `id` number is represented once, and it does not matter which `id` the `person` is attached to (i.e. 2/Jane and 4/Mary is equivalent to 2/Mary and 4/Jane). I tried using `row_number() over (partition by id order by person)` and then filtering by `row_number = 1`, but it resulted in the below:

```
id  person  description
1   John    The cat sat
2   Jane    The dog barked
3   James   The parrot
4   Jane    The dog barked
```

Mary is not represented, because Jane was row number one for both 2 and 4.

Comment: Because you should have partitioned by `Person` instead of by `id`.

Comment: it's not inherently correct - either permutation would work. updated my question to reflect that - thank you!

Comment: @TabAlleman I tried that as well - that results in one of the id numbers dropping off. so it would result in 4/Jane and 4/Mary

Comment: Maybe this could be fixed "in the earlier join"? This sounds a lot like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Did you backup your table before you inserted that way?

Comment: I wish...the problem is the earlier join can only join on `description`. so if a `description` is the same, the issue arises

Comment: understood. i'm confident that my starting dataset can't be changed much in previous queries/joins.

Comment: Well at this point you essentially have a many to many relationship across columns and rows in this result set. Sounds a LOT like another question earlier today that had much the same issue.

Comment: i think that's accurate - do you mind pointing me in the direction of that questions to see if it might help?

Comment: It wasn't answered either because this is absurdly difficult and defies the concept of relational data. I will see if I can find that other thread though. Maybe somebody has done something with it.

Comment: Here it is...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612642/select-rows-with-unique-values-in-two-columns

Comment: @SeanLange I updated my post with details on what went into the original dataset. understood that it's difficult...I have been struggling with it for a long, long time

Comment: This just absolutely screams of poor design. Why do you have the same description in two different (and seemingly unrelated) tables? You truly have a many to many between those two tables.

Comment: it's part of a stored procedure that is populating tables for a django app. person_description is the result of matching one list of people to another list of people and identifying pairs. those descriptions are then written to id_description. id_description has a many to many relationship with another table (id_person). This relationship is necessary for the django app. id_description can't hold `person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got here as a result of a join on Description, then one way you can fix this is to get TWO row_numbers().

Both Partition on Description.

One is ordered by ID, the other is ordered by Person.

Then Select the Descriptions with the Id and Person whose Row_Numbers match.

In pseudo, it should look something like this:

```
with cte_ID AS (SELECT Description, ID, {RowNumber ordered by ID} AS ID_RN...)
,    cte_Person AS (SELECT Description, Person, {RowNumber ordered by Person} AS Person_RN...)
SELECT ID, Person, Description
FROM cte_ID JOIN cte_Person ON Description=Description AND ID_RN=Person_RN
```

You could have done this in your original join by adding row_numbers (partition by Description) to each of your original tables, and joining on both Description and Row_Number.

Comment: this seems closer...but this results in only one record out of the four for `id` numbers 2 and 4. it results in 2/Jane and nothing else.

Comment: How did you construct it?   Basically you'll have to create two derived tables and JOIN them on the Description and Row_number.

Comment: this looks like it's working! let me tinker around for a bit to make sure, but thank you so much for the help up to this point

Answer (score 0):

use row_number window function

```
    with t as
(
select 1 as  id,'John' as person,'The cat sat' as des
union all
select 2 as  id,'Jane' as person,'The dog barked' 
union all
select 2 as  id,'Mary' ,'The dog barked' 
union all
select 3 , 'James' ,'The parrot'  
union all
select 4 , 'Jane' ,'The dog barked'  
union all
select 4 , 'Mary' ,'The dog barked'  

) select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by des  order by id ) rn 
 from t
) as t1 where t1.rn=1
union
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by des  order by person ) rn 
 from t
) as t1 where t1.rn=1

id  person  des             rn
1   John    The cat sat     1
2   Mary    The dog barked  1
3   James   The parrot      1
4   Jane    The dog barked  1
```

Comment: please check my comment above - this results in one of the `id` numbers dropping off